Draw two arrows between nodes in tikzpicture
I'm looking how to draw two arrows between nodes such as the red ones my image (the black one doesn't matter). I tried with south,east etc unfortunately I cannot have something like on the picture with that. Thanks.
 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, >=stealth, auto]
    % Define nodes
    \node[circle, draw] (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[circle, draw] (B) at (0,3) {B};
    \node[circle, draw] (C) at (-4,0) {C};
    \node[circle, draw] (D) at (-2,3) {D};
    \node[circle, draw] (E) at (-1.9,-2) {F};
    \node[circle, draw] (G) at (3,0) {G};
    \node[circle, draw] (Grade) at (3,3) {Grade};
    \node[circle, draw] (Indice) at (5,3) {Indice};
    \node[circle, draw] (H) at (3,-2) {H};
     \node[circle, draw] (I) at (6,-2) {I};
    % Draw arrows
    \draw[->] (Grade) -- (Indice);
    \draw[->] (Indice) -- (Grade);
   

\end{tikzpicture}



Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Use polar notation like \draw (Ind.170) — (Gr.10);

... or use yshift as in ([yshift=5pt]Grade.east) -- ([yshift=5pt]Indice.west) (but the arrow will then be only as long as it were if you used (Grade.east) -- (Indice.west), so it does not exactly touch the circles.

@JasperHabicht There's a way to avoid this problem, see my answer.

You could define the entry/exit point with the angle of entry/exit:
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, >=stealth, auto]
    % Define nodes
    \node[circle, draw] (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[circle, draw] (B) at (0,3) {B};
    \node[circle, draw] (C) at (-4,0) {C};
    \node[circle, draw] (D) at (-2,3) {D};
    \node[circle, draw] (E) at (-1.9,-2) {F};
    \node[circle, draw] (G) at (3,0) {G};
    \node[circle, draw] (Grade) at (3,3) {Grade};
    \node[circle, draw] (Indice) at (5,3) {Indice};
    \node[circle, draw] (H) at (3,-2) {H};
     \node[circle, draw] (I) at (6,-2) {I};
    % Draw arrows
    \draw[->] (Grade.20) -- (Indice.160);
    \draw[->] (Indice.-160) -- (Grade.-20);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Here's a style that draws two arrows, even if the nodes are not horizontal to each other. To do this, I calculate the angle between the nodes and move the arrow with transform canvas using the execute at begin to style.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
   
\tikzset{my arrows/.style={
        to path={},
        execute at begin to={        
            \draw[red,transform canvas={shift={(90+\n1:#1)}}]
            let
                \p1=(\tikztostart),
                \p2=(\tikztotarget),
                \n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}
            in (\tikztotarget)--(\tikztostart);
                            },
        execute at end to={        
            \draw[red,transform canvas={shift={(90+\n1:-#1)}}]
        let
            \p1=(\tikztostart),
            \p2=(\tikztotarget),
            \n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}
         in
            (\tikztostart)--(\tikztotarget);
            },
                            },
            my arrows/.default=5pt
} 

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, >=stealth, auto]
    % Define nodes
    \node[circle, draw] (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[circle, draw] (B) at (0,3) {B};
    \node[circle, draw] (C) at (-4,0) {C};
    \node[circle, draw] (D) at (-2,3) {D};
    \node[circle, draw] (E) at (-1.9,-2) {E};
    \node[circle, draw] (G) at (3,0) {G};
    \node[circle, draw] (Grade) at (3,3) {Grade};
    \node[circle, draw] (Indice) at (5,3) {Indice};
    \node[circle, draw] (H) at (3,-2) {H};
     \node[circle, draw] (I) at (6,-2) {I};
    % Draw arrows
    \draw[->,my arrows=5mm] (Grade) to (Indice);
    \draw[->,my arrows=5pt] (B) to (G);
   \draw[->,my arrows=5pt] (C) to (D);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


